# springboot + mongodb reactive , connection is getting closed immediately

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

Mongo connection is timing out on executing query

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:636) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1300(InternalStreamConnection.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.failed(InternalStreamConnection.java:587) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:319) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.handleReadResponse(NettyStream.java:350) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.access$1200(NettyStream.java:104) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener$1.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:499) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$OpenChannelFutureListener$1.operationComplete(NettyStream.java:496) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$CloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:1186) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:773) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:749) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:620) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.closeAll(NioEventLoop.java:769) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:526) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na] 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The connection to the server was closed
... 19 common frames omitted
```

running on java 11.

tried to set socket time out to 60s still fails. The connection to the server is getting closed immediately.

```
  uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/bankingdb?socketTimeoutMS=60000
```

Comment: Any news? We are facing the same issue.

Comment: The  thread was closing even before the mongo completes its action, had to make a blocking call for the wait.